# how to validate after pushing the data in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<select class="form-control input-sm text-uppercase" id="ddlUsers" data-ng -model="UserName" >
<option data-ng-repeat="List in Users" value="{{List.Value}}" ng-options="">{{List.Name}}
 </option>
</select>
```

controller code

```
var Users = [], filterCondition=[];
$(res).find('NewDataSet Table4').each(function () {
Users.push({
    Value: $(this).find('UserId').text(),
    Name: $(this).find('Name').text()
        });
    });
    $scope.Users = Users;
    $scope.UserName = $scope.Users[0].Value;
```

i want to show the select text based on the value equal to below code

```
 filterCondition.push({ operator: localStorage.getItem('UserId') });
```

Comment: Please explain your question more

Comment: if username has the following values like val1,val2,val3,val4 and filtercondtion has val3 if should show val3 on my drop down after satisfying condition